# Jekyll Pages Loop pulling all root files (including CSS and config)

Tags: ruby, jekyll

I'm using Jekyll to host my portfolio as well as blog. In a `{% for page in site.pages %}` loop, Jekyll is pulling everything with a root lvl folder, including my `css/main.css.`

When I start a new Jekyll project and write the same `for`-loop, I'm only given the Pages that have either `index.md` or `.html`. I could just port all my work over to a fresh install, but I'd like to understand what's happening.

I'm assuming this is some kind of config or cache error, but searching has turned up bupkis. Anyone have any insight on what's going on?

[Dom Structure w/ "Empty" nodes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3IxwC.png)
[Folder Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ReuV.png)

Comment: What is the `layout` on the first line of the pages that *do not* show up?

Comment: @IleEftimov layout: null. It's pulling my `feed.xml`, `css/main.scss` and something marked `/`, all as pages?

Comment: On further investigation, it's pulling the index.html from my root folder as a page entry too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`jekyll serve` or `jekyll build` will be generated all .html, .markdown, .md, or .textile files with a YAML Front Matter section. Other directories and files will be copied. [Jekyll structure](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/structure/)

.html, .markdown, .md, or .textile files with a YAML Front Matter section and the exception of posts (in _post), data files (_data) and files in _layouts, _includes, _plugins, _drafts are pages.

`{% for page in site.pages %}` processed with default configuration only these pages. But you can change the page scope.

_config.yml has a exclude option. You can exclude directories and/or files from the conversion.

Answer (score 1):

From `jekyll new mysite` (with version 3.x) command, you must get four pages from site.pages loop : about.md, feed.xml, index.html and css/main.scss.

If it's not the case : there is a problem.

From jekyll point of view a page is :

- anything that is not a document (post or collection item)
- and that have a front matter

If you only want to loop in pages that are generated in html, you can use `site.html_pages`.